# MySQL query for hotel rooms availability

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am doing a final year college project on hotel reservation system. The system lets many hotels to be added in the system by the respective hotel managers. The main problem here come is when the user wants to search the hotel room as per his/her requirement and I am not being able to find a proper solution for this. The situation here is user can reserve as many as required rooms from a hotel and there can be many hotels list in the search result.

User will not be displayed the hotel if the hotel's room and user's required no of rooms are not matched within the checkin and checkout date. The room is divided into two types single and double bed. User can only reserve one type of bed at a time.

Hotel Database
[image: Hotel database]

Room Database
[image: Room Database]

Reservation Database
[image: Reservation Database]

Reservedrooms Database
[image: Reservedrooms Database]

User will fill up the following form as advance search for the room availability search among the hotels. Query for the price range can be neglected

MySQL query for this will be really appreciated.

Advance Search form
[image: Advance Search]

I've tried following query to get the available room information but this query only gives the output from the first hotelid from hotel table with its room not in the reservedrooms table and also it doesn't validate the checkin and checkout date.

> sqlDate1 is checkin date formatted into sql date format and sqlDate2
>   is checkout date formatted into sql date format.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ROOM 
 WHERE ROOM.ROOMNO NOT IN 
    (SELECT RESERVEDROOMS.ROOMNO 
       FROM RESERVEDROOMS 
       JOIN RESERVATION 
         ON RESERVEDROOMS.RESERVATIONID = RESERVATION.RESERVATIONID 
      WHERE RESERVATION.CHECKINDATE NOT BETWEEN '" + sqlDate1 + "' AND '" + sqlDate2 + "')
```

Comment: What's the relevance of the checkin date to this problem?

Comment: If the room is in reservation table in checkin and checkout date then the room should not be counted to be available for the reservation.

Comment: Your query doesn't mention check-out

Comment: I don't know how to use checkout here. Can you help me with the query ?

Comment: The test for overlapping events is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: I think I need to do extra readings on what you are saying. If you can help me with the query it will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: OK I will have a read on that.